# Android: highlight button until other button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have 4 buttons in my layout - they are switchers between 4 possible contents of View. Any time one of these buttons is pressed I need to highlight it (simply load other background, other image and change the color of the text). Trouble is, I need this to be done from the moment button is touched (not AFTER the click) and until other button is pressed. Simple use of onClick() methods won't be very good because I'd have to check if other buttons are already highlighted, and also changes will be made only AFTER the click. Any good solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Button changes its color back after releasing the button. I also tried different combinations of android:state_pressed and android:state_focused - doesn't help.

Comment: UPD: solution was to set button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an `onFocusChange` listener?

```
button.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // set the background, image and color for focused
        } else {
            // set the background, image and color back to normnal
        }
    }
});
```

Set one of those for each button and you should be all set.